# Spivak Chapter 3 Lemma 3-7

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I don't understand why at the beginning Spivak talks about closed rectangles whereas later it seems he implicitly refers to open rectangles (because compactness is a statenemt about open sets).

The oscillation at a point is just the limit of the oscillation in an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of that point as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. So I find it obvious that the first statement is true for open rectangles. But Spivak probably doesn't refer to closed ones for no reason, does he? I can't see that reason.

Comment: What do you mean that ``compactness is a statement about open sets''? No it isn't, and open rectangles are certainly not compact.

Comment: Since $A$ is compact, there are finitely many of the closed rectangles $U_x$ whose interiors cover $A$. But then the corresponding closed rectangles $U_x$ also cover $A$.

Comment: @WSL the definition of "compact" involves (sub)coverings by open sets, that's probably what the OP means.